# android maps view blank

Tags: android-fragments, android-maps

I am following the steps in google but can't see my map in fragment. bellow is the code. if guys please help me?

I already added google-play-services_lib with my project. testing in real device. using Google APIs

```
Mainfest: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mymaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.mymap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mymap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mymaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY KEY" />
        <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

UI XML:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment    

    android:id="@+id/the_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.mymaps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;    

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            try {
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
                } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.print(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dec variable as global `private GoogleMap googleMap;`

`extends FragmentActivity` not `Activity`

after setContentView add this code

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
```

in xml

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

if you generate the googleMap api key with currect pakage name this will work

Comment: I tried as u write but it doesn't work, looks like same as b4 
had some error according to you previous code so modified a bit. bellow the the new code:
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
and
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
      SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.the_map);
getting same error

Comment: The problem is in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Without those two lines google can't detect that the android phone have google play services installed or not.

Comment: delete the "google-play-services_lib" from eclipse and workspace then import again with "Copy project into workspace" checked

Answer (score 2):

Put these lines on the AndroidManifest.xml file after the meta-data tag::

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"  
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Google has made it mandatory for android phones to have the google play services installed in order to use the map. So the tag checks for google play services is installed on the phone or not. If no, then it automatically redirects the user to google play site to get the required software installed..

If the problem still exists, then use this tutorial by Ravi Tamada and do not forget to add the lines mentioned in this answer.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/